# I'm writing a battleship AI in Java and I'm having trouble troubleshooting

Tags: java

There's a game file that runs my class and then calculates my average. It calculates the gameboard and gives me an array with the gameboard changes. It starts as a 10x10 of "." which get replaced by X if I hit or O if I miss. If I sink a ship it replaces all the X's(hits) with a number so if it was a destroyer with XXXXX it would become 55555.

When I run the game file and it gives me my average there is a ton of lines before the average saying out of guesses(max 100). I can't find out what is causing it to stop giving answers or bug up. Only thing I've noticed is if there's a hit on A1 and a miss on A2 leaving the only option as B2 it will sometimes give me A1. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class stug_Bot
{
    public static String makeGuess(char[][] guesses)
    {
        int row = 0; 
        int col = 0;
        int squareValue = squareType(guesses);
        int atkRow = -1;
        int atkCol = -1;
        int direction = 0;
        
        if (guessNumber(guesses) == 0)
        {
            row = ( 4 + (int)(Math.random() * 2));
            col = (4 + (int)(Math.random() * 2));
        }
        else if (hits(guesses))
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++)
            {
            for ( int j = 0; j < guesses[i].length; j++)
            
            if (guesses[i][j] == 'X')
            {
                atkRow = i;
                atkCol = j;
                break;
            }
            if (atkRow != -1)
            break;
            
            }
            
            
            
            while(true)
            {
                direction = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
                
                if (direction == 0 && atkRow != 0)
                {
                    if (targetUp(atkRow, atkCol, guesses) == -1)
                    break;
                    col = atkCol;
                    row = targetUp(atkRow, atkCol, guesses);
                    break;
                }
                else if (direction == 1 && atkCol < 9)
                {
                    if (targetRight(atkRow, atkCol, guesses) == -1)
                    break;
                    
                    row = atkRow;
                    col = targetRight(atkRow, atkCol, guesses);
                    break;
                }
                else if (direction == 2 && atkRow < 9)
                {
                    if (targetDown(atkRow, atkCol, guesses) == -1)
                    break;
            
                    col = atkCol;
                    row = targetDown(atkRow, atkCol, guesses);
                    break;
                }
                else if (direction == 3 && atkCol != 0)
                {
                    if (targetLeft(atkRow, atkCol, guesses) == -1)
                    break;
                    
                    row = atkRow;
                    col = targetLeft(atkRow, atkCol, guesses);
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        }
        else if (guessNumber(guesses) == 1)
        {
            do
            {
                row = ( 4 + (int)(Math.random() * 2));
                col = (4 + (int)(Math.random() * 2));
            } while (!isCorrectSquare(row, col, squareValue) || guesses[row][col] == 'X' || guesses[row][col] == 'O' || guesses[row][col] == '1' || guesses[row][col] == '2' || guesses[row][col] == '3' || guesses[row][col] == '4' || guesses[row][col] == '5');
        }
        else if (guessNumber(guesses) == 2)
        {
            do
            {
                row = (3 + (int)(Math.random() * 4));
                col = (3 + (int)(Math.random() * 4));
            } while (!isCorrectSquare(row, col, squareValue) || guesses[row][col] == 'X' || guesses[row][col] == 'O' || guesses[row][col] == '1' || guesses[row][col] == '2' || guesses[row][col] == '3' || guesses[row][col] == '4' || guesses[row][col] == '5');
        }
        else if (guessNumber(guesses) == 3)
        {
            do
            {
                row = (3 + (int)(Math.random() * 4));
                col = (3 + (int)(Math.random() * 4));
            } while (!isCorrectSquare(row, col, squareValue) || guesses[row][col] == 'X' || guesses[row][col] == 'O' || guesses[row][col] == '1' || guesses[row][col] == '2' || guesses[row][col] == '3' || guesses[row][col] == '4' || guesses[row][col] == '5');
        }
        else if (guessNumber(guesses) == 4)
        {
            do
            {
                row = (1 + (int)(Math.random() * 8));
                col = (1 + (int)(Math.random() * 8));
            } while (!isCorrectSquare(row, col, squareValue) || guesses[row][col] == 'X' || guesses[row][col] == 'O' || guesses[row][col] == '1' || guesses[row][col] == '2' || guesses[row][col] == '3' || guesses[row][col] == '4' || guesses[row][col] == '5');
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                row = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
                col = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
            } while (!isCorrectSquare(row, col, squareValue) || guesses[row][col] == 'X' || guesses[row][col] == 'O' || guesses[row][col] == '1' || guesses[row][col] == '2' || guesses[row][col] == '3' || guesses[row][col] == '4' || guesses[row][col] == '5');
        }
        
        char a = (char)((int)'A' + row);
        String guess = a + Integer.toString(col+1);
        
        return guess;
        }
        
    public static int guessNumber(char[][] arr)
    {
        int count = 0;
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j] != '.')
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    public static int squareType(char[][] arr)
    {
        int square = 0;
        
        if (arr[4][4] != '.')
        {
            square = 0;
        }
        else if (arr[5][4] != '.')
        {
            square = 1;
        }
        else if (arr[4][5] != '.')
        {
            square = 1;
        }
        else if (arr[5][5] != '.')
        {
            square = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            square = 0;
        }
        
        return square;
    }
    
    public static boolean isCorrectSquare(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (( z == 0 ) && ((x + y) % 2 != 0) || (( z == 1 ) && ((x + y) % 2 == 0)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean hits(char[][] arr)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j] == 'X')
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static int targetUp(int row, int col, char[][] map)
    {
       int target = 0;
       int count = 1;
       
       while(true)
       {
       if (row != 0 && map[row - count][col] == '.')
       {
           target = row - count;
           return target;
       }
       else if ( row!= 0 && map[row - count][col] == 'X')
       {
           count++;
       }
       else 
       {
        return -1;
        }        
        }
       
    }
    
    public static int targetRight(int row, int col, char[][] map)
    {
       int target = 0;
       int count = 1;
       
       while(true)
       {
       if (col+count < 10 && map[row][col + count] == '.')
       {
           target = col + count;
           return target;
       }
       else if ( col+count < 10 && map[row][col + count] == 'X')
       {
           count++;
       }
       else 
       {
        return -1;
        }
        }
       
    }
    
    public static int targetDown(int row, int col, char[][] map)
    {
       int target = 0;
       int count = 1;
       
       while(true)
       {
       if (row + count < 10 && map[row + count][col] == '.')
       {
           target = row + count;
           return target;
       }
       else if ( row + count < 10 && map[row + count][col] == 'X')
       {
           count++;
       }
       else 
       return -1;
       
        }
       
    }
    
    public static int targetLeft(int row, int col, char[][] map)
    {
       int target = 0;
       int count = 1;
       
       while(true)
       {
       if (col != 0 && map[row][col - count] == '.')
       {
           target = col - count;
           return target;
       }
       else if ( col != 0 && map[row][col - count] == 'X')
       {
           count++;
       }
       else 
       return -1;
       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this will require some debugging, did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Assuming what you posted is indicative of your code, get rid of all `static` methods and fields.  The only static method in your application should be the `main` method.  Break up your code into small (10 lines or less) testable methods.  Create classes for the game board and ship.  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Lots of code but nonetheless it is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was the `break` statements I was using in the else if (hits) section. If it picked a direction that had something blocking the way like a previous miss it would break the loop and return no value which led to the out of moves in a lot of the games. Replacing them with `continue` fixed it.